# Trying to display PHP echo in HTML with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to display two PHP echo messages from a seperate PHP file onto my HTML body page. Whenever you click the submit button the echo message should popup in the HTML page without redirecting me to the PHP page.

I need to connect to my two files through Javascript so I wrote a script attemtping to connect the HTML file with the PHP file.

My HTML:

```
<div id="formdiv">        
<form action="phpfile.php" method="get" name="fillinform" id="fillinform" class="js-php">
      <input id="fillintext" name="fill" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1">
            </form>
</div>
```

phpfile.php:

```
 $q = $_GET['fill'];
$y = 2; 
$work = $q * $y;
$bork = $work * $q;

echo json_encode($work) ."<br>"; 

echo  json_encode($bork);
```

Javascript:

```
 $(".js-php").submit(function()
    var data = {
    "fill"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + $.param(data); 

        $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url:"phpfile.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
        $(".formdiv").html(
        ""
        "Your input: ")
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You attached your logic to `.submit()` event and if you don't prevent default action, the form will be submitted to server. You can prevent it that way:

```
$(".js-php").submit(function(e) {
    // your code goes here
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Keen eye; didn't noticed

Comment: Hi @JeroenBellemans and Vitozev. It still doesnt work, whenever I press the submit button I get redirected to my PHP file. This is what Ive got so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/4t9q8af3/2/

Comment: Move`e.preventDefault();` outside `$.ajax({...})` call, just before closing brackets of `.submit()` - it will work.

Comment: Also, in your fiddle, you are closing the ajax request wrong. you did: `({ )}`, it should be `({ })`

Comment: @JeroenBellemans , Vitozev Alright, I belive I have fixed the problem, however I still get redirected to my PHP file. Here's the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/4t9q8af3/3/

Comment: Now your jQuery's selector is wrong: `$("js-php").submit()` should be changed to `$(".js-php").submit()`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to $(."js-php") now. But I still get redirected to the PHP page...

Comment: I noticed that on the top of `.submit()` you have `e.preventDefault()`, remove it.

Comment: Yes, but you have syntax errors in your code. You can use Developer Tools to debug your code, once you fix all syntax errors, it will work.

Comment: Alright, I managed to get rid of three syntax errors but the fourth one is still giving me the error: Uncaught reference error is not defined on this row. 

$(".js-php").submit(function(e){

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to append the data to your div like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $(".formDiv").append("Your input: " + data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your html you should try this below code :
If you want to replace the whole html inside the div having id="formdiv"

```
 success: function (data){
    $("#formdiv").html("Your input: "+data)
}
```

or

```
 success: function (data){
    $("#formdiv").text("Your input: "+data)
}
```

If you want to append data to the div having id="formdiv"

```
 success: function (data){
    $("#formdiv").append("Your input: "+data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add curly braces after `$(".js-php").submit(function(e)` and close it after your ajax ends.
2. Add `e.preventDefault()` before you call ajax so it will not redirect
   you to phpfile.php
3. Add `alert(data)` inside your function called at success of ajax.
4. there is a syntax error n line `$(".formdiv").html("""Your input: ");`

Your updated code should look like.

```
$(".js-php").submit(function(e){
    var data = {
    "fill"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + $.param(data); 
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url:"phpfile.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            alert(data);
    }
}
```